# oracle huge pages setup HugePages_Rsvd is 0

Tags: oracle, rhel6, oracle18c, huge-pages

I have been trying to switch from oracle AMM to ASMM huge pages. I have done the following changes on RHEL 6

Added following entry  in /etc/sysctl.conf ( as suggested by hugepages_setting.sh )

```
      vm.nr_hugepages=777
```

Added following entry in /etc/security/limits.conf

```
       oracle   soft   memlock    2831155
       oracle   hard   memlock    2831155
```

rebooted the server
changed oracle parameters memory_target, memory_max_target, sga_target, sga_max_target, use_large_pages to specific values.

After a database restart, I can see the following:

```
     [root@rheloracle ~]# grep -i huge /proc/meminfo
      AnonHugePages:         0 kB
      HugePages_Total:     777
      HugePages_Free:        8
      HugePages_Rsvd:        0
      HugePages_Surp:        0
      Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
```

And when I shutdown the database I could see the HugePages_Free is equal to HugePages_Total.

```
       [root@rheloracle ~]# grep -i huge /proc/meminfo
       AnonHugePages:         0 kB
       HugePages_Total:     777
       HugePages_Free:      777
       HugePages_Rsvd:        0
       HugePages_Surp:        0
       Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
```

Looks like HugePage configuration at db level and o/s level are in sync and in use. But all the examples and documents (i have referred) indicate that HugePages_Rsvd should have a non zero value after enabling huge pages. But same is not happening in my case. Can you please suggest if I am missing something or it's normal to have HugePages_Rsvd 0.

(I am running oracle 18c xpress edition on RHEL6)

Adding oracle parameters as per request

```
SQL> show parameter memory_target;

NAME                     TYPE    VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
memory_target                big integer 0
SQL> show parameter memory_max_target;

NAME                     TYPE    VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
memory_max_target            big integer 0
SQL> show parameter SGA;

NAME                     TYPE    VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
allow_group_access_to_sga        boolean     FALSE
lock_sga                 boolean     FALSE
pre_page_sga                 boolean     TRUE
sga_max_size                 big integer 1536M
sga_min_size                 big integer 0
sga_target               big integer 1536M
unified_audit_sga_queue_size         integer     1048576
SQL>
```

After decreasing SGA_TARGET to 1G.

```
[oracle@rheloracle dbs]$ grep -i huge /proc/meminfo
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:     777
HugePages_Free:      264
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
[oracle@rheloracle dbs]$
```

Comment: _RSVD>0 depends on your database memory configuration. Can you show us what you put in sga_max/target (memory_target should be zero for huge pages to be used)

Comment: @gsalem Edited the question to add the parameter values (  I believe they are set as per the documentations on HugePages). Please let me know if you need anymore details.

Comment: When you start your DB, it allocates what is needed by sga_target, and so in your case, you're left with 8 free pages . Try reducing sga_target a bit and see the difference.

Comment: I have decreased the sga_target and sga_max_size to 1G. Still HugePage_Rsvd is 0. Is it normal? if not, what am I missing? @gsalem

Comment: I think you should just look at the _used part, not the rsvd one.

Answer (score 0):

`HugePages_Rsvd: 0` is completely fine. This means that `sga` pages has been already read in the memory. If you want to populate pages in the `Rsvd`, set db settings `pre_page_sga=false;`.